# How to solve a Time-Dependent Workflow rule issue?

Tags: email-alert, time-dependent-workflow, workflowrule

I have a Time-Dependent Workflow rule with Evaluation Criteria: `Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria`

I need an e-mail alert to be send out `365 Days After Rule Trigger: Custom Date`

For that reason I added a Time-Dependent Workflow Actions `365 Days After After Rule Trigger: Custom Date`

Rule Criteria: `(Account: Custom Date NOT EQUAL TO null)`

The workflow rule is only working for newly created records.

I need to know how to make the workflow rule trigger and send an e-mail each time my "Date" field in the record is udpated?

As far as I'm concerned in order to make the worfllow rule trigger and send an e-mail when the Date field in the record is updated it has to unmeet and then meet the criteria.

I need to know how to be able to do that and make the workflow rule trigger and send an e-mail each time my "Date" field in the record is udpated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria- It works like Ischange()

But your problem,you can see stack exchange Link.It will helpful for you

[apply new workflow rule and action on existing records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/apply-new-workflow-rule-and-action-on-existing-records)

Comment: I reviewed the link, but I'm looking for a long term solution preferably without having to create a new custom checkbox field. Any ideas how to do that without additional custom field?